# How is Quartz.com make the background video move while scrolling on this page?

Tags: javascript, video, scroll, background, parallax

I'm wondering how one might mimic this effect on Quartz's website: http://qz.com/578040/see-why-people-call-this-guy-the-best-drone-racer-in-the-world/
is it parallax? or something else

Comment: Some new images on a scroll event perhaps?

Comment: it sure doesn't look like it... it appears that the video is going almost frame by frame when you scroll...

Answer (score 0):

It uses a long filmstrip picture and then uses javascript to translate up and down the filmstrip on scroll making it appear like it's a video.